# Can't run go commands after reinstall on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go

I have a ubuntu desktop, and I wanted to get rid of gccgo compiler on my machine.
I tried uninstalling following these steps:
http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/g/golang-go/uninstall.html

And after I ran sudo apt-get install golang-go whenever I try to execute a go command I get this:

```
Where op is one of cprtx optionally followed by v for verbose output.
For compatibility with old Go build environments the op string grc is
accepted as a synonym for c.

For more information, run
   godoc cmd/pack
# online_events/context_aggregator/fileman/csv_read
Usage: pack op file.a [name....]
Where op is one of cprtx optionally followed by v for verbose output.
For compatibility with old Go build environments the op string grc is
accepted as a synonym for c.

For more information, run
   godoc cmd/pack
# runtime/cgo
Usage: pack op file.a [name....]
Where op is one of cprtx optionally followed by v for verbose output.
For compatibility with old Go build environments the op string grc is
accepted as a synonym for c.

For more information, run
   godoc cmd/pack
```

Comment: the instructions you linked don't uninstall gccgo. Did you try running those commands with the gccgo packages?

Comment: Yes. I first uninstalled the gccgo package. It stilled compiled with gccgo, and then I tried reinstalling GO.

Comment: gccgo and go can co-exist just fine just fyi, I recommend installing Go from source instead since it looks like the ubuntu package is broken.